# Find out to which removed docker container a volume belonged to

Tags: docker

Is there a way to associate existing docker volumes (located in `/etc/docker/volumes`) to containers?

One way to do this is to use `docker inspect :conatiner_id` but this assumes that the container exists. How can you find to which container the volume belonged to, in the scenario that the container does no longer exist?

Answer (score 0):

Check docker volumes

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 14 14:27 0f801819cf76b04b6794163b65df5d649bd795e23f4fc778f78db9ac60a0180d
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 29 14:29 my-jenkins
```

For more info about your volume you can perform `docker volume inspect` but this tells you nothing about what's really inside your volume. The only way to know this is by going inside the volume-folder and check.

So I'll check "unamed" volume:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes/0f801819cf76b04b6794163b65df5d649
bd795e23f4fc778f78db9ac60a0180d/_data
...
drwx------    2 999      ping          4096 Nov 14 14:27 pg_tblspc
drwx------    2 999      ping          4096 Nov 14 14:27 pg_twophase
drwx------    3 999      ping          4096 Nov 14 14:27 pg_xlog
-rw-------    1 999      ping            88 Nov 14 14:27 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------    1 999      ping         20791 Nov 14 14:27 postgresql.conf
-rw-------    1 999      ping            37 Nov 14 14:27 postmaster.opts
```

Normally you should be able to link your volume to the old container you've used. You can check everything what's inside. There isn't a better way at the moment. This is actually the answer on your question but I'll give some more explanation to make it easier in the future.

The best way is to create named volumes. After deleting your container the volume will remain easy to recognize:

```
docker volume create --name my-jenkins
```

So in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` you'll see my-jenkins.

Now I start my jenkins container and link it with my named volume.
Everything which is in /var/jenkins_home will be stored in the named volume.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v my-jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

I'll create a job in jenkins with the name firstjob. You'll see this job in my named docker volume.

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes/my-jenkins/_data/jobs/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 dockrema dockrema      4096 Nov 29 14:47 firstjob
```

Now I will delete my container (id = fa1003894dbc). The container is gone:

```
$ docker rm -fv fa1003894dbc
```

I'm a bit later. I want to reuse the named docker volume which still exists to start a new jenkins container which will immediatly container the job "firstjob".

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v my-jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

If you have an unnamed docker volume (created automatically with name `0f8018x9cf76b04x163b6xdf`) you can use

```
docker run -d -v 0f8018x9cf76b04x163b6xdf:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Now your jenkins will use everything which is inside that volume (it's only not a named volume, what makes it more difficult to see with which type of container it was linked. But by accessing the volume folder you will find it in most cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. My question, however, was more generic i.e. the default docker volume naming which is a long string of numbers and letters. This way, by name only, the volume is indistinguishable from the rest.